# Transform the content in the tag using XSLT to characters based on the text

Tags: xslt

I need to transform the below XML based on the characters in the element. I have tried the below XSLT 1.0. In `<mo>` element, for `&#x007B;` and `&#x007D;`, should be transformed to |text{| and |text}| respectively. For `{` and `}` should be transformed to |cbo| and |cbc| respectively. But I am getting '|(text}||(text{||(text}||(text{|`for the contents in`` elements

Sample XML:

```
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><p><math display='block'><mo>{</mo><mo>&#x007B;</mo><mo>&#x007D;</mo><mo>}</mo></math></p></chapter>
```

XSLT 1.0 tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>    
</xsl:copy></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="m:mo">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(.)='&#x007B;'"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|(text{|</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="(.)='&#x007D;'"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|(text}|</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="(.)='{'"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|cbo|</xsl:text></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="(.)='}'"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|cbc|</xsl:text></xsl:when>
</xsl:choose></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So, what is the question? I don't see one/

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot reproduce the "problem"** -- the output produced by the provided XSLT code doesn't contain a substring of:

```
"|(text}||(text{||(text}||(text{|"
```

**The provided, unreadable code can be simplified to the following simple code** -- do note that DOE isn't needed at all:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="m:mo">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=". = '&#x007B;'">
     <xsl:text>|(text{|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=". = '&#x007D;'">
     <xsl:text>|(text}|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=". = '{'">
     <xsl:text>|cbo|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=". = '}'">
     <xsl:text>|cbc|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both, the original code and its equivalent readable and simplified code (above), produce the same result**(when we don't take into account indentation or lack of such):

```
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <p>
      <math display="block">|(text{||(text{||(text}||(text}|</math>
   </p>
</chapter>
```

I don't know whether this result is "good" or "bad", as the OP hasn't specified what results he wants to be produced, what result he is getting, and why the result he is getting isn't "good".

Comment: Result want to produce: <chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><p><math display="block">|cbo||(text{||(text}||cbc|</math></p></chapter> for the given XML Input using XSLT 1.0. Please note that XSLT parser (SAXON) is processing both the '&#x007B;' and the character '{' as the same way. But through XSLT I am need to differentiate it. When entity &#x007B; comes in <mo> it should be transformed to |(text{| and when charcter { comes it should be transformed to |cbo|.

Comment: @siva2012, An XSLT processor *cannot* distinguish between a character and its corresponding character reference -- they are both provided to the XSLT processor as the same code-point -- by the XML parser, that produces an XML document for the XSLT processor. This is a purely *lexical* difference and it is lost before the XSLT processor gets activated in the processing chain. Therefore, such a problem (not commenting on its supposed meaning...) cannot and shouldn't be solved with XSLT. preprocessing, at the XMLReader level is needed to replace one of the two, with something really different.

Answer (score 1):

> When entity `&#x007B;` comes in  it should be transformed to |(text{| and when charcter `{` comes it should be transformed to |cbo|.

Once your XML has been through an XML parser, these two inputs are indistinguishable. It's a bit like saying you want to process them differently depending on whether the author typed the text with his left hand or his right hand - they are just different ways of inputting the same data.

If you want to distinguish them, you will need to do some kind of preprocessing so that the difference is retained through XML parsing. One way to do that is Andrew Welch's Lexev tool, which is integrated with KernowForSaxon. However, I would question your design; depending on a lexical difference like this will make your system very fragile.